# Process.Start not passing along Arguments

Tags: vb.net, command-line-arguments, process.start

I have a bat file that runs the following perfectly fine:

```
Bec.exe --f=Config.cfg
```

Now in vb.net I have a button that starts the same exe with the same arguments, and outputs to a rtb.  However it does not pass along the arguments for some reason, I don't know why. Can anyone help?

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim cmdProcess As Process
    cmdProcess = New Process()
    cmdProcess.StartInfo.FileName = """" & TextBox2.Text & """" 'normally this is C:\ServerTools\Bec.exe
    cmdProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = """" & TextBox1.Text & """" 'normally is --f=Config.cfg
    cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    cmdProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False

    If cmdProcess.Start() Then
        RichTextBox2.Text = cmdProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd
    Else
        ' Failed to execute
    End If
End Sub
```

Also I'll provide a reference of the accepted options to the .exe I'm starting

```
Options:
-h, --help            show this help message and exit
-f FILENAME, --file=FILENAME
```

Comment: Have you checked what `.Arguments` is actually set to?

Comment: the contents of TextBox2 are '--f=Config.cfg'

On button2 click it just runs the exe without the arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory property.

Answer (score 0):

I've always done this by creating a separate [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5zzxthe.aspx) object and passing that into the `Process.Start()` method.

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("filename.txt", "-arg1 -arg2");
Process.Start(psi);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still need cmd output redirected to my richtextbox2

Comment: You can still pass a ProcessStartInfo object to your specific instance of a Process.

Answer (score 0):

You should not quote the arguments, nor the exe path

```
cmdProcess.StartInfo.FileName = TextBox2.Text
cmdProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = TextBox1.Text
```

Comment: This was the first thing I tried, I still had no luck getting it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across a solution, apparently I had to be running my program in the same directory as the exe I was executing.  the -f Config.cfg argument is normally based off the location of where Bec.exe is, well when I was calling it through my program it was basing it off of my programs location, so now that I have my program in the same directory it's working now.